# “your device isn't compatible with this version”

Tags: android, app-store, incompatibility

I have an app on the google play app store for more than two years with more than 8000 download and its a paid app. recently i received a mail from one of the customers saying that he had been using the app over two years and recently he updated his devices with latest os versions
after which he is not able to install the app from the app store. No updates have been pushed from developer end. the customer gets the error " your device is not compatible with this version" but the app is of the 
same version that he had been using. what could be the error. any suggestion pls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="au.example.test"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="12"
    android:versionName="1.0" >



    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Check your manifest file, did you happen to set `android:maxSdkVersion` in uses-sdk?

Comment: yes, i am using minsdkversion=8 from the beginning and never changed it... and no maxsdkversion is mentioned

Comment: Then you might want to take in-depth look into your source code. There could have some code that is deprecated in new os version. Check thru all your annotation first especially those with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml you can specify the minimum and maximum sdk version in this form:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Change your maxSdkVersion to the latest android sdk version(18), then it should work

Answer (score 0):

This may or not make a difference but it is recommended that you target a particular API level. It may be worth setting the target sdk version to the latest android release and ensure it is working as expected.